# Issue with PF30 BB on Boost frame - 2-3mm crank arm clearance

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket

I have a brand new Titanium Boost 29er hardtail.  The frame uses a PF30 BB and the BB shell is 73mm wide.

I have installed the recommended RaceFace cinch PF30 bottom bracket with a Race face Next SL crank - 175mm arms and 32t single chain-ring.

The problem is that the clearance between the chain stay and the crank arm is next to nothing.  There is no contact yet but I am unable to run the recommended crank boot protector.

[image]

The instruction for this BB so not to use any spacers since it 73mm (68mm ones use spacers).

Adding spacers wont help as it does not lengthen the spindle.  I do not see how a Shimano XTR/XT crank will work here either since it has the same Q-factor.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaceFace makes cinch spindles in various lengths. I assume you have a [version for 68/73mm bottom brackets](http://www.raceface.com/products/details/cinch-spindle-kit-68-73mm). There's also a [100mm bottom bracket spindle option](http://www.raceface.com/products/details/cinch-spindle-kit-100mm). It will certainly fit, but Q-factor might become too wide for your liking. Theoretically, you can also order a custom length spindle and spacers from some CNC manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks pal,  there is a pdf from Race face with the different spindle lengths.    On there they note a RF143 seems to be the next one up after the 68/73mm one I have  but looking on their website they only have 3 options.   see link here: https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEu-SS9qPMAhUEipQKHYCcCskQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raceface.com%2Fmedia%2FCrank_Q-factors_and_chainlines.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEF0WNbzsyDjxj3G73PCgvkfCwwYw&sig2=2ABkz02f_zOG1swaGCS0aA&bvm=bv.119745492,d.dGo

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of options. I'd email them and ask about everything directly.

Comment: Update on this:  I emailed raceface and eventually got an answer back.  They collaborated with the manufacturer of my frame and the guys are arranging a RF143 spindle for me which the correct one to use on my bike.  Thanks for your interest and advice.